# Central Authentication Service (CAS) with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications

I am developing a web application with **ruby on rails**. I am trying to link the authentification page of my webapp to a **Central Authentication Service (CAS)**.
So, whenever someone tries to start my webapp , my app should :

- Check if the user is already connected to the CAS

  1/ if he is already connected, the app will start and he can use its services normally

  2/ if the user is not connected to the app, a login page will be displayed, where he has to type his password and login. These password and login will be tested on the CAS, and according to the result of the test will be allowed to start the webapp or not.

This seems a bit complicated to implement. I need help because i am new to ruby on rails.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the devise gem, 
here is a railscast to show you how [railscast example](http://railscasts.com/episodes/233-engage-with-devise?view=asciicast)

and [here is the gem link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

here is a [CAS specific gem](https://github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable) for devise

hope that helps

Comment: the problem is how to use devise to connect to a CAS..that's specific